# Object data becomes empty after serializing

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
    user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()

carts = AddToCart.objects.filter(user=user)

sum_price = 0
for i in carts:
    sum_price += int(i.product.price)

context = {
    'carts': carts,
    'sum_price': sum_price,
}
print(context)

serializer = AddToCartSerializer(context, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

**printed 'context' in a terminal looks like this {'carts': <QuerySet [<AddToCart: AddToCart object (3)>]>, 'sum_price': 100}. But after serializing it becomes empty. Can someone help me?
**

**This is an output in a postman**

```
[
{},
{}
]
```

**AddToCart models.py**

```
class AddToCart(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**AddToCartSerializer serializers.py**

```
class AddToCartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='User')
product = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='Product')

class Meta:
    model = AddToCart
    fields = ['user', 'product']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code.

views.py:

```
# context = {
#    'carts': carts,
#    'sum_price': sum_price,
# }
print('result1', carts)
serializer = AddToCartSerializer(carts, many=True)
data = {
    'carts': serializer.data,
    'sum_price': sum_price,
}
print('result2', data)
return Response(data)
```

serializers.py:

```
class AddToCartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AddToCart
        fields = ['user', 'product']
        read_only_fields = ['user', 'product']
```

Comment: Output changed to this 
{
    "carts": [
        {}
    ],
    "sum_price": 100
}

Comment: But carts is still empty

Comment: Print like me and show me the result

Comment: result1 <QuerySet [<AddToCart: AddToCart object (3)>]>
result2 {'carts': [OrderedDict()], 'sum_price': 100}

Comment: I guess the serializer is wrong.
It is necessary to check whether the usage of the `source` parameter of `ReadOnlyField` is correct. Use the serializer I wrote and check the output.